# EXTJS 4.2 ajax dirty proxy data

Tags: extjs

my question is simple. Is there a way to tell ajax proxy to send **all** data back to server by calling sync(). Not only dirty?

Comment: Use `writeAllFields` on the writer.

Comment: This property refers to only 1 record of the recordset.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you have to iterate over all records in the store and call [setDirty()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-setDirty) to achieve this.

Comment: Strangely when doing this extjs makes 1 extra request that uncommits dirty records that were updated from grid. Maybe I shouldnt mark a record dirty twice.

Comment: This happens because server response failing this way. Is there a way to get ajax firstly from 1 URL and post dirty data to other?